# Script to connect to a web page

Tags: python

Looking for a python script that would simply connect to a web page (maybe some querystring parameters).

I am going to run this script as a batch job in unix.

Comment: "Connect to a webpage" is really vague.  What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Answer (score 11):

[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) will do what you want and it's pretty simple to use.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

params = {'param1': 'value1'}

req = urllib2.Request("http://someurl", urllib.urlencode(params))
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)

data = res.read()
```

It's also nice because it's easy to modify the above code to do all sorts of other things like POST requests, Basic Authentication, etc.

Comment: Please let me know if HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate. Frank(ftchang@MIT.EDU)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
aResp = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com/");
print aResp.read();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need your script to actually function as a user of the site (clicking links, etc.) then you're probably looking for the python mechanize library.

[Python Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Answer (score 2):

A simple [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) called from a shell script might suffice.

Answer (score 2):

in python 2.7:

```
import urllib2
params = "key=val&key2=val2" #make sure that it's in GET request format
url = "http://www.example.com"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url+"?"+params).read()
print html
```

more info at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html
in python 3.6:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
params = "key=val&key2=val2" #make sure that it's in GET request format
url = "http://www.example.com"
html = urlopen(url+"?"+params).read()
print(html)
```

more info at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html
to encode params into GET format:

```
def myEncode(dictionary):
    result = ""
    for k in dictionary: #k is the key
        result += k+"="+dictionary[k]+"&"
    return result[:-1] #all but that last `&`
```

I'm pretty sure this should work in either python2 or python3...

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you're just trying to fetch a web page, [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is a pre-existing (and very common) tool that does exactly that.

Basic usage is very simple:

```
curl www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to simply use httplib from the standard library.

```
myConnection = httplib.HTTPConnection('http://www.example.com')
```

you can find the official reference here: http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html