# 404 Client Error with requests function for yahoo financials

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

404 Client Error with requests function for yahoo financials, direct click the following URL is no problem

> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL

```
import requests
a = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL')
a.raise_for_status()
```

**OR**

```
import urllib
req = urllib.request.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL")
data = req.read()
```

**result**

```
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL
```

Comment: Interesting problem. I've noticed this works fine via `curl` too.

Comment: Do other libraries also perform the same? [libraries_via_stack_thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401941/script-to-connect-to-a-web-page)

Comment: import urllib
req = urllib.request.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL")
data = req.read()

Comment: dear, same problem @Agnij

Comment: dear, yes, very interesting @rv.kvetch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject user agent

```
import requests

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36'}
    
a = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL',headers= headers)
a.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Just add the Headers in your `get` method you will get response as
>    200
> 2. You can find Headers from First go to chrome developer mode and
>    Network  refresh site  then find your URL and go to Headers you will find
>    all data

```
import requests
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL",headers=headers)
res.status_code
```

Output:

```
200
```